# prefer-web-inf-classes, не работает Servlet в контексте Spring

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

Пишу приложение на `java`, сделал авторизацию с `weblogic` и  `Servlet` в контексте `Spring`(`MyServlet extends ASpringContextIncludedServlet`). В `weblogic.xml` пишу :

```
<container-descriptor>
     <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
 </container-descriptor>
```

проблема в том что: 
Если стоит флаг **true** то не работает Авторизация но  работает `Servlet`
а если стоит флаг **false** то  Авторизация работает  но `Servlet` не работает
(пишет `Exception` `[ServletContext@295575305[app:com.example.myWeb module:com.example.myWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war path:/MyWeb spec-version:2.5]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)` ).

в чем может быть проблема? И как можно его решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй поменять на обычный сервлет `HttpServlet`

Comment: я хочу в контексте Spring :  ASpringContextIncludedServlet